# How to open sql project/solution from my Desktop to another laptop?

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I made a software application with c# and it is connected to my sql on my own desktop and We have to present it to our professor so I connected my application with on my friend's laptop but I can't run the program because the server from my sql is the server that I used on my desktop and I can't open my sql project or solution on her laptop as well. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: So, you are not able to run application or not able to access database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You both need to be connected over network (LAN). Then, first check your friend laptop IP address and try accessing your database server using IP-address. For example :

```
 http://localhost:port/
```

to

```
 http://ip-address-:port/
```

Similar change, you need to make in your code as well.